# Encoder timebase is not set error when rendering

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video, frame-rate

So I shot a scene with my camera, and imported it into blender's video editor. I then proceeded to splice the video and audio in at least a dozen places.
[image: Video and Audio Splice Setup]
When I try to render my finished video, I go the error 'The encoder timebase is not set' I'm not sure how ti fix this.

I've been looking around all day and haven't found a viable solution. [This page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102689/the-encoder-timebase-is-not-set?rq=1) suggests changing the FPS up, and then back to what it was to reset it, but when I change it, the audio gets all screwed up with the audio segments running over each other (as seen below).
[image: Messed up audio]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the sequencer?

Comment: How would I do that?